# \0 getting appened in string while converting it from stream

Tags: c#

I have written a wcf service which is getting some xml data from Navision and then writing it to a 
file.

```
public Stream getXML(Stream data){
string strXML = "";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data, Encoding.UTF8);
strXML = reader.ReadToEnd();
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML);
```

in strXML, I am getting a string like this.

```
< ? x m l   v e r s i o n = " 1 . 0 "   e n c o d i n g = " u t f - 1 6 " ? > .....
```

[image: /0 getting appended can be seen while debugging. Image attached]

```
strXML.Replace("\0", string.Empty)
```

saving my life otherwise it's throwing

```
Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 2.
```

why this "\0" getting appended and how to prevent this? any help?

Comment: It looks like the XML stream is encoded using Encoding.Unicode rather than Encoding.UTF8.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have tried with Unicode but no result.

Comment: It's likely that whatever is supplying the `Stream data` parameter is what needs to open the stream using Encoding.UTF8. Just changing your `StreamReader()` to use Encoding.Unicode is not likely to work - that should stay as `Encoding.UTF8`, and the source needs to change to `Encoding.UTF8` too.